# background image property in css does not work

Tags: java, css, javafx-11

I tried to add a CSS code to my java application, the CSS code is working fine with all CSS properties unless the -fx-background-image("") URL it shows

CSS code

```
.body
{
    -fx-background-image: url("http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird4.jpg");
}
```

javafx code

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

forget to add the error sorry here its : javafx.css.converter.URLConverter resolve